# WSO2 PKIX path building failed for signup page

Tags: java, ssl, wso2, ssl-certificate, wso2-api-manager

I have successfully deployed WSO2 API Manager 2.6 which uses certificate signed by our internal CA. All API store, publisher, admin functionalities are working fine except self-signup.
I have browsed thousands of threads and followed almost all suggestions. I have done following to resolve the issue:

1. Added internal CA public certificate and site public certificate to the client-truststore.jks
2. Added internal CA public certificate and site public certificate to the jre's cacerts
3. I also have jdk installed on machine so I added internal CA public certificate and site public certificate to the jdk's cacerts.
4. I am allowing all hosts by setting httpclient.hostnameVerifier=AllowAll
5. I am using YAJSW to run it as service in Windows environment. I added following to the JVM parameters as seen below:

   wrapper.java.additional.29 = -Dhttpclient.hostnameVerifier=AllowAll

   wrapper.java.additional.30 = -Dorg.wso2.ignoreHostnameVerification=true

   wrapper.java.additional.31 = -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${apim_home}\repository\resources\security\client-truststore.jks

Of course I restarted service multiple times after making each changes.. and now here is the error I am getting:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-04-25 13:15:42,949] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} -  org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (/store/site/blocks/user/sign-up/block.jag#10) {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager}
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (/store/site/blocks/user/sign-up/block.jag#10)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:65)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (/store/site/blocks/user/sign-up/block.jag#10)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.user.sign_up.c0._c_anonymous_2(/store/site/blocks/user/sign-up/block.jag:10)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.user.sign_up.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/user/sign-up/block.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_28(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:287)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_29(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:347)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_28(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:282)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_52(/store/jagg/jagg.jag:715)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c0.call(/store/jagg/jagg.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.c2._c_anonymous_1(/store/site/pages/sign-up.jag:11)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.c2.call(/store/site/pages/sign-up.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.c2._c_script_0(/store/site/pages/sign-up.jag:10)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.c2.call(/store/site/pages/sign-up.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.c2.call(/store/site/pages/sign-up.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.pages.c2.exec(/store/site/pages/sign-up.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:535)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.SelfSignUpUtil.executeGet(SelfSignUpUtil.java:353)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.SelfSignUpUtil.getConsentPurposes(SelfSignUpUtil.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:240)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621)
    ... 99 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
    ... 105 more
```

Comment: Is this a single node setup?

Comment: No. I have active-active setup with Windows Network file share (NFS) for the deployment.

Comment: Please someone can help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: You may want to install the entire certificate chain to the truststore.

Comment: I installed the complete certificate chain to the truststore  and not just my certificate. As I mentioned earlier, I also pass the jvm parameter when service start to make sure that my WSO2 truststore is being used and not jre's by passing parameter javax.net.ssl.trustStore. I still added my whole certificate chain to the Jre's truststore. I also applied certificate to Trusted CA's in my windows certificate store. I also added certificate and its chain to a client computer from which I am trying to open signup url (though, I am sure it is not a problem)